# How to tell quarkus to start with a random free port? And how to read assigned port number?

Tags: quarkus

Is there a way in Quarkus to tell it to start with a random but free http-port and how can the application internally read out this port-number?
This question might make more sense in the context of the upcoming command-mode support (https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/7681). Effectivelly, I am trying to write a UI application based on Quarkus. The steps should be:
1. Start Quarkus with a random http port that is free
2. Read out the port-number and open a browser window (opening index.html under localhost:random-port)

As a workaround i can randomly choose a port number (it might be free with high probaility), set it as as System property to force Quarkus to use it.

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is super easy:

1. Just put next line into **application.properties**:

```
quarkus.http.port=0
```

2. In place where you want to get port, use DI to get value of this config property(you can use `String` as well if needed isntead of `Integer`):

```java
@ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.http.port")
Integer assignedPort;
```

Comment: Is there anyway we can get the port value as part of a lifecycle call?

Answer (score 0):

I would put the service in a container, then you would use `-P`

Dockerfile

```
FROM somejavaimage
EXPOSE 8080  # some port

COPY . /app  # copy some code
# TODO: Build some code

RUN ...   # some java process
```

CLI

```
docker build -t . quarkus_image
docker run --rm -P quarkus_image  # forwards a random port on host to container's 8080
```

> trying to write a UI application based on Quarkus

For scalability, I would write the API in Quarkus, then the frontend UI in a separate web server container (like Nginx hosted Vuejs)