# Quarkus Get HTTP listening port at startup

Tags: java, quarkus

I'm trying to get the port Quarkus is listening for HTTP connections on at startup (so that I can send a message to Consul to register the service).

The `quarkus.http.port` property is set to `0` so that a random port is selected at startup. I'm send the message to Consul in an `@Observes StartupEvent` method, but the `quarkus.http.port` property is null at this point. If I add a timer and schedule a function to run after 10 seconds, the `quarkus.http.port` property *does* contain the port.

It seems that my `onStartup` function is ran before Quarkus has actually opened the HTTP port. Is there anyway that I can schedule `onStartup` to execute after the port has been opened?

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class TestClass
{
    public void onStartup(@Observes StartupEvent event)
    {
        String port = System.getProperty("quarkus.http.port");
        // port is null here
        Log.infof("Port: %s", port);

        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                String port = System.getProperty("quarkus.http.port");
                // port contains a string like "41069"
                Log.infof("Port: %d", port);
            }
        }, 7000L);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately when using the random port, there is no good way to be notified when the real port is set

Comment: For now I've written a function that just polls that property every 100 ms. It's not great, but it works.

Comment: can you try with this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/61170000/175554

Comment: I've tried that too, but that too resulted in the same issue. The property was set to `0` and would never be changed into the actual value

Answer (score 0):

To get the runtime value, inject the `io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.HttpConfiguration` class.

```
    private final URI rootUri;
    public UserEndpoint(HttpConfiguration httpConf) {
        try {
            if (httpConf.ssl.certificate.files.isPresent()) {
                rootUri = new URI("https://" + httpConf.host +
                        (httpConf.sslPort == 443 ? "" : ":" + httpConf.sslPort)
                        + "/");
            } else {
                rootUri = new URI("http://" + httpConf.host +
                        (httpConf.sslPort == 80 ? "" : ":" + httpConf.port)
                        + "/");
            }
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```